# Exception class to control input of strings?

Tags: c++, exception

How does one control that input goes appropriately and neatly in a long row of input requests such as this? I was thinking of using try/catch blocks but this seems the wrong/long way around of doing things. Any tips / point me to the right path would be much appreciated.

```
    cout << "First Name?: ";
    cin >> first;
    cout << "Last Name?: ";
    cin >> last;
    cout << "Middle Name?: ";
    cin >> middle;
    temp->setName(first, middle, last);
    cout << "ID number? (5 digits): ";
    cin >> ID;
    temp->setId(ID);
    cout << "Age?: ";
    cin >> age;
    temp->setAge(age);
    cout << "Phone number?(ie. ##########): ";
    cin.ignore(); 
    getline(cin, ph);
    temp->setPhone(ph);
    cout << "Address Street Number?: ";
    cin >> addressNum;
    cout << "Address Street Name?: ";
    cin >> addressName;
    temp->setAddress(addressNum, addressName);
    cout << "Gender?: (M or F) ";
    cin >> gender;
    temp->setGender(gender);
    cout << "E-mail?: ";
```

Comment: Depends on how you want to handle errors. Maybe `if(cin >> first)` may be the right way for you to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use do while loop to control the correct input. I have shown for id number only.

```
    int flag;
    do
    {
         flag=0;
        cout << "ID number? (5 digits): ";
        cin >> ID;  //as integer type so convert it to string
        string Result;          // string which will contain the result

        ostringstream convert;   // stream used for the conversion

        convert << ID;      // insert the textual representation of 'Number' in the characters in the stream

        Result = convert.str();
        if(Result.length()!=5)// check id exacly 5 digit
        {
          cout<<"Error!\n";
          flag=1;
        }
    } while(flag);
   temp->setId(ID);
```

And you have to include a header file `#include<sstream>`